# Finding Limit of a two-variable exponential function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to find the following limit (if exists) considering $x,y > 0$

$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \exp(-x/y - i/y) $

The presence of $x/y$ strongly suggest that it doesn't exist, but Wolfram Alpha returns that the limit is 1. Even more weird is that Wolfram Alpha returns "doesn't exist" for the slightly different limit

$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \exp(-x/y - i/y) - 1$

If the first limit exist and equal to 1, shouldn't the second also exist and equal to 0?

Comment: Is that $i$ equal to $\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: What is the order of the limits: $\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0}$ or $\lim_{y\to0}\lim_{x\to0}$? My guess is that the limit does not exist you will get a term like $\exp({i\infty })$, which is badly defined

Comment: Be careful with the statement that $x/y$ strongly suggests that the limit doesn't exist.  For example, consider $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\exp(-1/x)$.  This limit is $0$ because as $x$ approaches $0$, $-1/x$ approaches $-\infty$ and the exponential approaches $0$ as its argument decreases to negative infinity.

Comment: Yes, $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\exp(-x/y-i/y)=\exp\left(\frac{-x-i}{y}\right)$$
$x$ to 0 is not a problem
$$\exp\left(\frac{-i}{y}\right)$$
If $i$ is the imarinary unit $i^2=-1$
$$\cos\left(\frac{-1}{y}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{-1}{y}\right)$$
which keeps oscillating as $y$ gets smaller and smaller, so the limit does not exist.

If $i$ is a real number, the left-limit differs from the right-limit (one is $\exp(+\infty)=\infty$ and the other is $\exp(-\infty)=0$), so the limit also does not exist.